# Showing that $A_{n} \cap B_{n} \to A \cap B$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $A,B, A_{n}, B_{n} \in \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$. I have managed to show that if $A_{n} \to A$ and $B_{n} \to B$, then $A_{n} \cup B_{n} \to A \cup B$ using the  relation that $$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} (A_{n} \cup B_{n}) = \limsup_{n \to \infty}A_{n} \cup \limsup_{n \to \infty}B_{n}$$

How can I show that $A_{n} \cap B_{n} \to A \cap B$ if $A_{n} \to A$ and $B_{n} \to B$?

My impulse is just to show that $A_{n}^{c} \cup B_{n}^{c} \to A^{c} \cup B^{c}$ using the fact that $A_{n} \cup B_{n} \to A \cup B$, together with the fact that if $A_{n} \to A$, then $A_{n}^{c} \to A^{c}$ and likewise for the $B_{n}$'s.

Comment: What is your definition of $A_n\to A$ ?

Comment: $A = \lim_{n \to \infty} A_{n} = \limsup{A_{n}} = \liminf{A_{n}}$, provided the latter two quantities agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is in fact obvious since

$$\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{p\geq n}A_p\cap B_p=\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{p\geq n}A_p\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{p\geq n}B_p\right)=A\cap B$$

and

$$\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{p\geq n}A_p\cap B_p=\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{p\geq n}A_p\right)\cap\left(\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigcap_{p\geq n}B_p\right)=A\cap B$$

Comment: I'm not sure if a substitute of this identity is supposed to simplify some expression, or if this just directly implies that $A_{n} \Delta B_{n} \to A \Delta B$ and $A_{n} \cap B_{n} \to A \cap B$. Can you clarify?

Comment: Your comment helps show why it's true, but I'm unclear how to use it to make the proof work. I feel inclined to assert the result on noting that $\lim_{n \to \infty}(A_{n} \Delta B_{n} = A \Delta B$, but for such an elementary exercise, I don't think it's reasonable for me to assume this as well. I can prove it, but that makes the proof burdensome.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Forget my previous post, I re edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Though I guess you want to replace the $A_{n}, B_{n}$'s with $A_{p}, B_{p}$'s.

Comment: On second thought, I think your answer might be wrong.

Your first line amounts to saying that the limsup of the intersection is equal to the intersection of the limsup's, but that's not true in general. 

That being said, the result still follows from your argument (with my correction in mind), because the liminf of the intersection is contained in the limsup of the intersection.

Comment: "Your first line amounts to saying that the limsup of the intersection is equal to the intersection of the limsup's, but that's not true in general." You right, it's not true in general. But here it is true since $A_n\to A$ and $B_n\to B$. That's why this exercice has no really sense to me since it's obvious.